# Changing Multiple Images in the cell of RecyclerView on the basis of time interval

Tags: java, android, multithreading, imageview, android-databinding

I am trying to make a recyclerview's cell on which the image ll change after every 2 seconds.
For that I have made a binding adapter and I am using this method in the row of recycler view

```
    @BindingAdapter("android:imageChanging")
public static void imageChanging(ImageView imageView,List<Drawable> drawableList){

    try {
        new Runnable() {     //changing images of ads after every two seconds
            // creating a new runnable for every ad cell
            int updateInterval = 2000; //=two second
            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {

                imageView.setImageDrawable(drawableList.get(i));
                i++;
                if (i > drawableList.size() - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                imageView.postDelayed(this, updateInterval);
            }
        }.run();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Logger.logCrashlyticsException(e);
    }


}
```

The problem I am facing is that it causes jerk after scrolling when coming fromsecond page to 1st.

Comment: have you found the solution yet?